# WinPac-8000 OPC-server network access

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, network-protocols, opc

I am to build an automation solution based on WinPac-8000 controller (http://www.icpdas.com/products/PAC/winpac/introduction.htm).

I split this project into 2 programs: 1st is running on the controller (it does some business logic) and second operates on user machine (it displays current results). The problem is: I use build-in OPC server (named 'quicker'). It has nice intergration with C# and easy to use in the 1st program to access connected devices.

But I dont know how to access OPC-server from the second program through network. I have absolutely no idea where to start.

Links or any kind of advice will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to merely to add a 'comment' to your question, but do not have the necessary rep, so I shall comment as an answer...

Please could you clarify what you would like the second program to do? OPC has 'client' and 'server' components. The OPC 'server' would run on the WinPAC controller and you would run OPC 'client' software on the PC. Here are some OPC .NET links: [Open Automation](http://www.opcconnect.com/dotnet.php), [OPC and .NET](http://www.opcconnect.com/dotnet.php).

However, if you merely wish to monitor and control digital/analog points, the [MODBUS/TCP](http://www.rtaautomation.com/modbustcp/) protocol is much simpler and cleaner to implement ([CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Modbus_TCP_class.aspx)).

OPC is quite heavy and I have not found it particularly robust in unstable networks. MODBUS/TCP is a simple socket connection and can easily be implemented in any language supporting TCP sockets. ICPDAS and MODBUS/TCP has worked extremely well for me.

Comment: Basically the second program allows user to read and write some OPC tags (seems like some kind of a 'OPC-client'). The only conceptual difference from the 1st program is that it is not located on WinPac, and I dont know which  'technology' or 'library' to use to connect this program and OPC-server

Comment: Depends on exactly what you want to do with the OPC tags? 

For basic tasks, SCADA (supervisory control and data acquisition) or HMI (Human Machine Interface) software will do the trick.

For more sophisticated control/monitoring, you can use the .NET OPC SDK (http://www.opcfoundation.org/Downloads.aspx?CI=281).